# Passing a mongodb query from json file to execute in python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I have a `json` file with around 50 queries.
The `json` file look like this:

```
{

   "1": {
     "mongodb":"mydb1.mongodbtime.find({\n    \"timestamp1\": {\"$gte\": datetime.strptime(\"2010-01-01 00:05:00\", \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"),\n                   \"$lte\": datetime.strptime(\"2015-01-02 00:05:00\", \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\")}},\n    {\"id13\":1}),",
     "mongodb1index":"mydb1.mongodbindextimestamp1.find({\n    \"timestamp1\": {\"$gte\": datetime.strptime(\"2010-01-01 00:05:00\", \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"),\n                   \"$lte\": datetime.strptime(\"2015-01-02 00:05:00\", \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\")}},\n    {\"id13\":1}),"
   },
   "2": {
     "mongodb":"mydb1.mongodbtime.find({\n    \"timestamp1\": {\"$gte\": datetime.strptime(\"2010-01-01 00:05:00\", \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"),\n                   \"$lte\": datetime.strptime(\"2015-01-02 00:05:00\", \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\")}},\n    {\"id13\":1}),",
     "mongodb1index":"mydb1.mongodbindextimestamp1.find({\n    \"timestamp1\": {\"$gte\": datetime.strptime(\"2010-01-01 00:05:00\", \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"),\n                   \"$lte\": datetime.strptime(\"2015-01-02 00:05:00\", \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\")}},\n    {\"id13\":1}),

   }

}
```

I have two `collections` one named `mongodbtime` and one called `mongodbindextimestamp1` in the database `mongodbtime`.
The code i have used in python for passing the `query` and execute it look like this:

```
mydb1 = myclient["mongodbtime"]


with open("queriesdb.json",'r') as fp:
    queries = json.load(fp)
    db = {"mongodb": "mongodbtime", "mongodb1index": "mongodbtime"}
    for num_query in queries.keys():
        query = queries["1"]
        print(query)
        for db_name in db:
            print(db_name)
            run(query[db_name])
```

```
def run(query):

        for j in range(0, 1):
            
            start_time = time.time()
            cursor = query
            for x in cursor:
                pprint(x)

            # capture end time
            end_time = time.time()
            # calculate elapsed time
            elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
            times.append(elapsed_time)
            #elapsed_time_milliSeconds = elapsed_time * 1000
            #print("code elapsed time in milliseconds is ", elapsed_time_milliSeconds)
        finalmeasurments(times)
```

I passed it like a string and obviously when i `print(cursor)` it just `print` the `query` Should i use another form of file?
Any idea on how i should execute my `query`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a choice, refactor your approach. If you need to run a set of tests, create an Enum class with the parameters in and iterate the class.

If you must use a JSON file, consider [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) but YMMV.

Comment: what do you mean by ymmv?

Comment: generally eval type functions are considered bad practice and likely very hard to debug if things don't work.

Comment: i have one question more to ask.i use this code to benchmark postgres performance vs mongodb performance..do you think using eval add a lot execution time?

Comment: Sorry I've no idea.